# Dataset of automobile factories

Tags: data-request, industry, cars

Where can I find a list of automobile factories in the world with GPS? The more additional attributes like production size, number of employees, etc is included the better. Wikipedia contains some lists of a few vendors but information included is very poor and unstructured